# File is always null in srpingboot 1.3.7 when processing multipart/form-data request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, grails, groovy

I am trying to communicate a grails application with a springboot application. I am trying to upload a file to the springboot application, that is previously uploaded to grails.
This is the code of my springboot controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    def save(@Valid @ModelAttribute SaveRequest request) {
        //Some logic
}
```

The saveRequest class contains some validations that need to be applied to the request

```
class SaveHotelAccreditationRequest {

    //Other fields

    @NotNull
    MultipartFile image

}
```

I have set the properties in the application.properties file like so

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled = true
spring.http.multipart.location=/home/user/temp
```

I am using both commons-io and commons-fileupload libraries by Apache.
I have set the multipart resolver like this

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(2*1024*1024);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

This is the code in my grails application

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password))
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build()
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url)
        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
        reqEntity.addBinaryBody('image', file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, file.getName())
        //Other fields
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity.build())
        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine())
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost)
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------")
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine())
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()))
        } finally {
            response.close()
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close()
    }
```

And when i run the request i get the following error message:

```
2020-05-02 02:37:24 | WARN | org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved
 exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validatio
n.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'saveHotelAccreditationRequest' on field 'image': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.saveRequest.image,NotNull.image,NotNull.org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [saveRequest.image,image]; arguments []; default message [image]]; default message [may not be null]
```

I have tried using postman and i get the same error message. I cannot figure out what i am missing here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring-Boot REST for multipart APIs, I am writing my multi-part APIs like this

```
@PostMapping("/upload-doc")
@ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", name = "payload", dataType = "UploadDocRequest")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ApiOperation("Upload User's documents")
public UploadDocRequest uploadDocRequest(
        @RequestPart("payload") UploadDocRequest payload, @RequestPart("docs") MultipartFile[] docs) {
```

Spring Multipart config in yaml

```
spring:
 servlet:
  multipart:
   max-file-size: 5MB
   max-request-size: 5MB
```

And How to call it from PostMan-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While working with Multipart , the following has worked for me in Spring boot.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadVideo")
public void uploadVideo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    // logic here
}
```

and the multipart resolver which you are using for max size can be configured in properties file like this

```
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

This I am calling from Angular App like this

```
var reqHeader=new HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader.append('contentType','multipart/form-data')
    let options = { headers: reqHeader, params: new HttpParams()
                          
                   };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file )
    return this.http.post(this.url_toreadFile,formData,options)
```

Hope it might provide some help in your implementation.